# JSON/XML parsing & jQuery callback for processing output json

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, json

**Case 1: What does not work for me?**

```
$phpObj=json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
```

In above file_get_contents returns me a json, I convert that to php object using above and then I parse $phpObj (to extract certain strings) which is a multidimensional array and just form a new array of key value say $newObj. After that I simply convert newObj to json using json_encode.

I use jQuery to parse the $newObj and it renders it to html.

**Case 2: What does work for me?**

Instead of parsing json I get my server to return XML and instead of json_decode like above I use:

```
$xmlDoc->load($url);
```

I parse the XML create the $newObj (key value pair) & then I use jQuery same like above which renders  the recordset on browser. Works perfectly fine.

Now the only difference between case 1 and 2 ofcourse other than parsiong JSON and XML is the value that jQuery receives in the callback function for rendering:

For Case 1 (does not work):

```
{"1002":"I am Yavar","1003":"I work for XYZ","1004":"California is in US"}
```

For Case 2 (works):

```
[{"1000":"California is in US","xmlNode":{}},{"1001":"I work for XYZ","xmlNode":{}}]
```

It would be great if somebody could help me as to what is going wrong in case 1 and are the square brackets ([]) and xmlNode stuff coming in case 2 really required to make it work?

If really required here is my jQuery function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#term').keyup( function() {

  $.get('search_json.php?q='+escape($('#term').val()), function(data) {
    html = '<table id="results">';
    $.each( data, function( ind, ep ) {
        html += '<tr><td class="document"><b>'+ind.key+'</b>&nbsp;';
        html += +ep.value+'</td></tr>';
    } );
    html += '</html>';
    $('#results').replaceWith( html );
  } );
} );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do an $.each() on an object that has non zero indexed keys. The reason method two works is because it is returning it as an array of objects, instead of one object.

Use method two, or loop through your json object and simply spit it out as:

```
$outObj = array(); // Don't forget to initialise your arrays!
foreach($phpObj as $key => $value) {
   $value['key'] = $key;
   $outObj[] = $value; 
}
json_encode($outObj);
```

Creates an internal array which will be iterable using the Javascript you suggested. You will need to refer to `ep.key` instead of `ind.key` though.

Comment: Thanks TomHallam: This does help. Now I am getting slightly different json objects. I have posted another question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354892/different-output-json-formats. Your help would be appreciated, I am an absolute beginner in User Interfaces :)